# loop Read_csv to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to load all .csv files from a folder into a list of seperate dataframes for each file

the folder is called coins.

```
for file in './coins': 
    logs_total = [pd.read_csv('./coins/'+file, engine='python')]
```

The error:

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './coins/.'
```

without engine='python' its :

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop does not reference the files in the `coins` folder.  All Python knows is that `'./coins'` is a string, and you are iterating over each letter in that string.

Also, if you want to build a list of data frames with a for loop, you should create the list outside of the loop first and append to it (or you can use a list comprehension).

To access the files, you can import the either `os` or `glob` to get the file names.  Here is an example using `os`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

log_total = []
for file in os.listdir('./coins'):
    log_total.append(pd.read_csv('./coins/'+file))
```

Here is an example using `glob` and a list comprehension.

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

log_total = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob('./coins/*.csv')]
```